# Intended activity not being called

Tags: android, android-activity

This is the code of the activity i want to call.
    package se.anyro.nfc_reader;

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import se.anyro.nfc_reader.record.ParsedNdefRecord;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mposclient.MainActivity;

/**
 * An {@link Activity} which handles a broadcast of a new tag that the device just         discovered.
 */
public class TagViewer extends Activity {

private static final SimpleDateFormat TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat();
private LinearLayout mTagContent;

private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
private NdefMessage mNdefPushMessage;

private AlertDialog mDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tag_viewer);
mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
resolveIntent(getIntent());

mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setNeutralButton("Ok", null).create();

mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
if (mAdapter == null) {
showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.no_nfc);
}

mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
mNdefPushMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { newTextRecord(
            "Message from NFC Reader :-)", Locale.ENGLISH, true) });
}

private void showMessage(int title, int message) {
mDialog.setTitle(title);
mDialog.setMessage(getText(message));
mDialog.show();
}

private NdefRecord newTextRecord(String text, Locale locale, boolean encodeInUtf8) {
byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes(utfEncoding);

int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);

byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
data[0] = (byte) status;
System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);

return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if (mAdapter != null) {
if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.nfc_disabled);
}
mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
mAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(this, mNdefPushMessage);
}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
if (mAdapter != null) {
mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
mAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
}
}

private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
String action = intent.getAction();
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
NdefMessage[] msgs;
if (rawMsgs != null) {
msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
}
} else {
// Unknown tag type
byte[] empty = new byte[0];
byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
byte[] payload = dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();

NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { record });
msgs = new NdefMessage[] { msg };             
}
// Setup the views
buildTagViews(msgs);
}
}

private String dumpTagData(Parcelable p) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Tag tag = (Tag) p;
byte[] id = tag.getId();
sb.append("Tag ID (hex): ").append(getHex(id)).append("\n");
sb.append("Tag ID (dec): ").append(getDec(id)).append("\n");

String prefix = "android.nfc.tech.";
sb.append("Technologies: ");
for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
sb.append(tech.substring(prefix.length()));
sb.append(", ");
}
sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
if (tech.equals(MifareClassic.class.getName())) {
sb.append('\n');
MifareClassic mifareTag = MifareClassic.get(tag);
String type = "Unknown";
switch (mifareTag.getType()) {
case MifareClassic.TYPE_CLASSIC:
type = "Classic";
break;
case MifareClassic.TYPE_PLUS:
type = "Plus";
break;
case MifareClassic.TYPE_PRO:
type = "Pro";
break;
}
sb.append("Mifare Classic type: ");
sb.append(type);
sb.append('\n');

sb.append("Mifare size: ");
sb.append(mifareTag.getSize() + " bytes");
sb.append('\n');

sb.append("Mifare sectors: ");
sb.append(mifareTag.getSectorCount());
sb.append('\n');

sb.append("Mifare blocks: ");
sb.append(mifareTag.getBlockCount());
}
if (tech.equals(MifareUltralight.class.getName())) {
sb.append('\n');
MifareUltralight mifareUlTag = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
String type = "Unknown";
switch (mifareUlTag.getType()) {
case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT:
type = "Ultralight";
break;
case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT_C:
type = "Ultralight C";
break;
}
sb.append("Mifare Ultralight type: ");
sb.append(type);
}
}  
return sb.toString();
}

private String getHex(byte[] bytes) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
int b = bytes[i] & 0xff;
if (b < 0x10)
sb.append('0');
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
if (i > 0) {
sb.append(" ");
}
}
return sb.toString();
}

private long getDec(byte[] bytes) {
long result = 0;
long factor = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
result += value * factor;
factor *= 256l;
}
return result;
}

void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) {
return;
}
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
LinearLayout content = mTagContent;

// Parse the first message in the list
// Build views for all of the sub records
Date now = new Date();
List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);

final int size = records.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
TextView timeView = new TextView(this);
timeView.setText(TIME_FORMAT.format(now));
content.addView(timeView, 0);
ParsedNdefRecord record = records.get(i);
// line which displays the text 
content.addView(record.getView(this, inflater, content, i), 1 + i);
content.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_divider, content, false), 2 + i);
byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
String data = new String(payload);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

String[] words = data.split(" ");  
Intent callMain=new Intent(TagViewer.this,MainActivity.class);
callMain.putExtra("expid", words[0]);
callMain.putExtra("exname", words[1]);
callMain.putExtra("exprice", words[2]);
startActivity(callMain);
}
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
setIntent(intent);
resolveIntent(intent);
}
}
```

This is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.accountmanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="se.anyro.nfc_reader.TagViewer"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mposclient.ProductList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.AccountDetails"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.ClientActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.ClientTabsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.Credentials"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mposclient.DBHelper"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mposclient.ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mposclient.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mposclient.ParseData"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.Options"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_options" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.SwipeCard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_swipe_card" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.Transaction"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_transaction" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.DatabaseHelper"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_database_helper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.TransList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trans_list" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.accountmanager.MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem here is i want to start the activity TagViewer but when the application is run, Some other activity is being called and it is non responsive i cant click on its buttons etc.
Please check if there is any error in the code because the log doesnt show any error it is just not opening the right activity

This is what the logcat shows.

```
Installing AccountManager.apk...
Success!
Project dependency found, installing: nfc-reader
Uploading nfc-reader.apk onto device 
Installing nfc-reader.apk...
Success!
Starting activity se.anyro.nfc_reader.TagViewer on device 4df7e2387663cf87
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=  [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]    cmp=com.example.accountmanager/se.anyro.nfc_reader.TagViewer }
```

Comment: Post the code that starts this Activity.

Comment: I have put it as launcher check the manifest file

Comment: Look in the logcat (don't filter the logcat) and you will see what activity is being started. Android logs a ton of stuff that is useful for debugging in the logcat.

Comment: You should also remove all the <intent-filter> tags from your normal activities where all you have is <category...DEFAULT> set.

Comment: Please format your code (4 space indents). It is impossible to read!

Comment: This is what the logcat shows

Comment: I have put it up in the question Please check @David Wasser

Comment: So you see, Android is starting your `TagViewer` activity.

Comment: But here the problem is the xml file or activity which is starting is not tagviewer but it is starting some other activity on my cell phone